# JavaScript countdown between 2 dates

Tags: javascript, date, countdown

I want to display a HTML countdown that takes 2 dates where `dateEnd` has 30 days more than `dateStart`.
The date objects are being passed properly, but the `getCountdown()` function only displays the `days` left, while the `minutes`, `hours` and `seconds` don't change:

```
function renderCountdown(dateStart, dateEnd){

    console.log(dateStart, dateEnd); 
    // Logs 
    // Sat Dec 19 2015 11:42:04 GMT-0600 (CST) 
    // Mon Jan 18 2016 11:42:04 GMT-0600 (CST)

    let currentDate = dateStart.getTime();
    let targetDate = dateEnd.getTime(); // set the countdown date
    let days, hours, minutes, seconds; // variables for time units
    let countdown = document.getElementById("tiles"); // get tag element
    function getCountdown(){
        // find the amount of "seconds" between now and target
        let secondsLeft = (targetDate - currentDate) / 1000;
        days = pad( parseInt( secondsLeft / 86400 ) );
        secondsLeft %= 86400;
        hours = pad( parseInt( secondsLeft / 3600 ) );
        secondsLeft %= 3600;
        minutes = pad( parseInt( secondsLeft / 60 ) );
        seconds = pad( parseInt( secondsLeft % 60 ) );
        // format countdown string + set tag value
        countdown.innerHTML = "<span>" + days + "</span><span>" + hours + "</span><span>" + minutes + "</span><span>" + seconds + "</span>"; 
    }
    function pad(n) {
        return (n < 10 ? '0' : '') + n;
    }   
    getCountdown();
    setInterval(function () { getCountdown(); }, 1000);
}
```

Here's the HTML `#tiles` tag after render:

```
<div id="countdown">
  <div id="tiles"><span>30</span><span>00</span><span>00</span><span>00</span></div>
  <ul class="labels">
    <li>Days</li>
    <li>Hours</li>
    <li>Mins</li>
    <li>Secs</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**UPDATE** Working code for future reference.
Thanks to @deamentiaemundi:

```
function renderCountdown(dateStart, dateEnd){
    let targetDate = dateEnd.getTime();
    let days, hours, minutes, seconds; 
    let countdown = document.getElementById("tiles");
    let count = 0;
    let getCountdown = function (c){
        let currentDate = new Date().getTime();
        let secondsLeft = ((targetDate - currentDate) / 1000) - c;
        days = pad( Math.floor( secondsLeft / 86400 ) );
        secondsLeft %= 86400;
        hours = pad( Math.floor( secondsLeft / 3600 ) );
        secondsLeft %= 3600;
        minutes = pad( Math.floor( secondsLeft / 60 ) );
        seconds = pad( Math.floor( secondsLeft % 60 ) );
        countdown.innerHTML = "<span>" + days + "</span><span>" + hours + "</span><span>" + minutes + "</span><span>" + seconds + "</span>"; 
    }
    function pad(n) {
        return (n < 10 ? '0' : '') + n;
    }   
    getCountdown(count++);
    setInterval(function () { getCountdown(count++ ); }, 1000);
  }
```

Comment: Are you following ES6? Because you used some features that were not allowed in ES5

Comment: Just for the `let` declarations. What features should I change?

Comment: What's wrong? The difference from `Sat Dec 19 2015 11:42:04 GMT-0600 (CST)` to `Mon Jan 18 2016 11:42:04 GMT-0600 (CST)` is 30 days, 00 hours, 00 mins, 00 secs.

Comment: @JanEglinger but how I start the countdown from there? To make it 00 00 00 00 with an interval of 1000ms

Comment: The calls to getCountDown() don't calculate a new current date and time; they still use the one that was calculated in renderCountdown().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A little hint:

```
function renderCountdown(dateStart, dateEnd){

    console.log(dateStart, dateEnd); 
    // Logs 
    // Sat Dec 19 2015 11:42:04 GMT-0600 (CST) 
    // Mon Jan 18 2016 11:42:04 GMT-0600 (CST)

    let currentDate = dateStart.getTime();
    let targetDate = dateEnd.getTime(); // set the countdown date
    let days, hours, minutes, seconds; // variables for time units
    let countdown = document.getElementById("tiles"); // get tag element
    let count = 0;
    var getCountdown = function (c){
        // find the amount of "seconds" between now and target
        let secondsLeft = ((targetDate - currentDate) / 1000) - c;
        days = pad( Math.floor( secondsLeft / 86400 ) );
        secondsLeft %= 86400;
        hours = pad( Math.floor( secondsLeft / 3600 ) );
        secondsLeft %= 3600;
        minutes = pad( Math.floor( secondsLeft / 60 ) );
        seconds = pad( Math.floor( secondsLeft % 60 ) );
        // format countdown string + set tag value
        console.log(days + ", " + hours + ", " + minutes + ", " + seconds); 
    }
    function pad(n) {
        return (n < 10 ? '0' : '') + n;
    }   
    getCountdown();
    setInterval(function () { getCountdown(count++ ); }, 1000);
}

renderCountdown(new Date("Sat Dec 19 2015 11:42:04"),new Date("Mon Jan 18 2016 11:42:04") )
```

Output is console now, to avoid cluttering. I added a counter to actually *count* down and increment it every call.

Comment: Thanks, this is working. I added an update for other developers to use the working code.